# 30w USB-C 3-in-1 charger UK plug

Tags: charger

In the Apple Store in Chicago, USA I bought a Mophie 3-in-1 charger. I am now in the UK and carrying a US-to-UK plug adaptor is zero fun. So I am seeking a compact 30w UK pinned unit that is compact enough to fit in the lovely Morphie grey felt case.

Pictures of what is the official UK Morphie 3-in-1 folding plug that I cannot find online is as below:

[image]

[image]

Although any equivalent part that fits inside the grey felt case would be fine. The folded dimensions of that official USB-C part that fits are 28mm x 45mm x 75mm.

I have tried searching but I only get very bulky 30w units that are for a MacBook else compact folding 20w units that won't power the Morphie 3-in-1 (the phone will charge but not a watch plus phone together). Any help to find a compact UK-pinned 30W compact charger would be most welcome.

Thanks!

---

**Update:**

@Tetsujin very helpfully posted a link to the "morphie Speedport 30w GaN fast wall charger". It seemed to be a little oversized but I bought it and creates a slight bulge in the fabric case. So while it  works and I will use it I am still looking for one that fits better in the case. Here are the shots of that solution:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. What's wrong with the one pictured? [other than I doubt it conforms to British electrical standards] You can get them here on import from dealers who also don't care if they're compliant or not. Notably, though, Apple sells a lot of Mophie stuff on the Store, but not those [so perhaps they're paying more attention to standards than some others]

Comment: that is a UK morphie that comes with a UK plug that isn't what get when you buy in the USA which comes with a US plug. so that is what i am looking to obtain. i have edited my question to make it clearer that that is what i ideally seek but anything equivalent would be fine.

Comment: Apple sells a *legal* one for the UK. https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/HPZG2B/A/mophie-speedport-30-1-port-gan-wall-charger-30w That plug is not to British Standard, so otherwise you could only buy it abroad or from dodgy grey importers. I found one yesterday, but the search eludes me today.